# spherical geometry algorithm for astronomy (moving a telescope)

Tags: geometry, astronomy

I cannot get my head around the maths / geometry for this, but I am *sure* there is a simple (ish) algorithm for this.

Trying to control a telescope on alt/azimuth, and I need to sole the following problem.

I *know* my lat/long - I definately know where my house is. 
From this, I know what angle polaris / centre of rotation of starfield is at, and what bearing.

I know how long an astronomical day is in secs, so how long one full rotation of starfield will take. 
I want to calculate how much a given point in the sky will move (in say one second) in terms of delta-x (rotation of scope horizontally, azimuth), and delta-y (elevation of scope in degrees, altitude). 
I know which point in sky I am looking at as I have compass and inclinometer readings from device on my scope.

- A star *close* to polaris in view will move only a small dx and dy as
  it tracks a small piece of sky.  A star moving from due east to due
  west will track a much larger path in sky, as it sweeps over the
  largest track.  A star much more southerly will track reducing
  amounts of dx and dy.

Does anyone know how to compute dx and dy given lat/long, direction and elevation of scope ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an algorithm and I can even get you a open source code to do that. You just have to explore the Toshimi taki (japanese amateur astronomeur & programmer) website:

[Toshimi Taki Website!](http://www.geocities.jp/toshimi_taki/)

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer as the right one in case it helps :) It's an algorithm that allows you to control both a dobson/equatorial telescope. It's very well known among amateur astronomers.

Comment: I can see the dob-alt-az to eq conversion, but I can't see how to compute dx and dy as T changes, all in alt-az. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi David, Taki's code allows you to do that but you have to explore the algorithm. Contact him if you need help. He already answered some of my questions.

Comment: Could you make it David? How did it go?